# matplotlib and opencv typerror imagedata cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

there i am getting an error

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

i can't figure out what the solution is my code is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('hello,jpg',0)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation= 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([]) #to hide tick values of x and y-axis
plt.show()
```

and here is my error log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "matplotliOpenCv.py", line 8, in <module>
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation= 'bicubic')
File "/home/rijalboy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2684, 
in imshow
None else {}), **kwargs)
File "/home/rijalboy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 
 1599, in inner
  return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
 File "/home/rijalboy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
 return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/rijalboy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/rijalboy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 
 5679, in imshow
 im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/rijalboy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 685, 
 in set_data
 "float".format(self._A.dtype))
 TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

i cannot solve this problem i tired many method related on google search please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What does `print(img)` show after the `imread` line?

Comment: @GPhilo it shows None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment: `print(img)` prints `None`, hence `img` doesn't get loaded because `cv2.imread` silently fails (with OpenCV you should always check the return values, as it often won't raise errors in case things don't work as expected).

The numpy TypeError is just a consequence of the image not being loaded. Make sure the path is correct and the file exists (and is not broken).